# Displaying double value in a JLabel

Tags: java

I need one of my JLabel's, lblLength, to display between 0 and 2 with 0.1 intervals. I tried taking the value of the slider "length_slider" and adjusting it before setting it on the lblLength, however this didn't work. If someone could tell me what is wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

```
public class label_display implements ChangeListener {

JLabel v;
String name;

label_display( JLabel v){// grab the JLabel
    this.v=v;
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {



    JSlider slider = (JSlider)e.getSource();



    if(!slider.getValueIsAdjusting()){  
        name = slider.getName();        
        if(name=="length_slider"){      
            double adjuster = slider.getValue();
        adjuster=adjuster/10;
        String temp =  Double.toString(adjuster);
        v.setText(temp);
        }
        else{                           
            String temp =  Double.toString(slider.getValue());
            v.setText(temp);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `Double.toString()` try `String.valueOf()`. Also, if you received any errors, please share them.

Comment: dont compare strings with `==` use `.equals()`

Comment: @chancea when I use .equals() I get a NullPointerException error.

Comment: @chancea It actually works [I tested it](https://gist.github.com/czipperz/1b89192cb7f9b840f441) in Java 8

Comment: @Czipperz so why do i get a NullPointerException?

Comment: nvm, .equals() is working now, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @pepper cool. I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Looking at the source code shows that they just call each-other btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals() to compare objects not == as suggested by @chancea.  .equals() compares if the two Strings are the same ("asdf".equals("asdf") is true but "asdf" == "asdf" is false.)

New code should look like:

```
if(name.equals("length_slider")){
```

instead of

```
if(name == "length_slider"){
```

Comment: Side note: `"asdf" == "asdf"` is true because when Java compiles the code any string literals that are the same in string value are stored in the same place, making this evaluate to true.